# Cómo pasar de un string a un array

Tags: java, array, string

Pues supongamos que tengo un string de este formato:

```java
"{2 4},{20 15}"
```

y tengo que convertirlo en un array de arrays o un array bidimensional. He probado con replace suprimiendo las llaves y después cortando con split para así, intentar meter cada número en un array independiente. Puede parecer sencillo pero la cosa se complica cuando también tengo que manejar un string parecido pero más grande, pongamos:

```java
"{2 4 6},{20 15 4},{10 12 30}, {4 3 16}"
```

Además también usé .trim() para intentar quitar los espacios en blanco, pues no puedo convertirlos a Integer, pero entonces me considera que los numeros entre llaves son uno solo. En otras palabras:

```java
"{2 4},{20 15}"
```

lo devuelve así:

```java
{24,2015}
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo, que como se ve, ha de ser genérico?

EDIT: 
La solución buscada sería:

```java
{{2 4},{20 15}}
```

Comment: ¿siempre va a ser la misma longitud de items por fila?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? El string del input puede cambiar claro, como he puesto en los dos ejemplos. ¿Te refieres a eso?

Comment: por ejemplo, en este caso: `"{2 4 6},{20 15 4},{10 12 30}, {4 3 16}"` todos los objetos entre `{ }` tienen 3 números, en el primer ejemplo tienes `"{2 4},{20 15}"` 2 números por cada objeto, ¿Siempre es constante o podría variar como `"{1 2 4},{20 15}"` donde hay 3 y 2 números?

Comment: Ah eso, entonces no. Siempre manejas el mismo número de números (valga la redundancia) entre las llaves. O bien 2 o 3 o el que sea.

Comment: En ese caso, te dejo una idea inicial: realiza un split basado en la coma, con eso te dará un arreglo, luego dentro de cada arreglo, procede a hacer otro split basado en un espacio, con eso te dará todos los números.

Comment: ¿Y qué pasan con las llaves? También tengo que quitarlas porque si no, el método Integer.parseInt(); me va a lanzar una excepción cuando se encuentre una llave y no un número.

Comment: puedes hacerle un integer TryParse o algo así

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo resolví de esta manera

No soy experto en Java, pero aquí tienes la lógica, seguro la podrás optimizar

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {

        String modelo = "{2 4 6},{20 15 4},{10 12 30}, {4 3 16}";
        Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\s?\\d+)+)");

        String[] split = modelo.split(",");

        String[][] matriz;

        matriz = new String[split.length][];
        for ( int i = 0; i < split.length; i++ ){
            Matcher match = patron.matcher( split[i] );

            while (match.find()) {
                matriz[i] = match.group(1).split(" ");
            }

        }

        // esto muestra el resultado
        for( int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++ ){
                System.out.println( matriz[i][j] );
            }
            System.out.println( "----------" );
        }

    }
}
```

Funciona perfecto con estos patrones:

```
{2 4 6},{20 15 4},{10 12 30}, {4 3 16}

{{2 4},{20 15}}

{2 4},{20 15}
```

#### lógica

- Al modelo de datos lo se pago por coma, para conseguir un array de cada uno de los elementos
- A cada item del array de aplico una expresion regular con el patron de los datos para capturarlos..
- Al resultado que me arroja la expresión regular, le aplico un `split` por espacio, y obtengo el array de datos.

Te dejo [acá](https://regex101.com/r/wbzKea/1) los patrones que utilicé, para conseguir la expresion regular